# How to compile a third party extension from github?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have never work in any `vscode` extension neither witch `nodejs/npm`

im trying to compile this extension:
[gutter-preview](https://github.com/kisstkondoros/gutter-preview)

I have download `nodejs`, installed, then i download the extension source, open cmd:

`cd 'folder where is the extension src' > npm install package.json`

it installed and created a folder `node_modules`

am i doing it correctly? what's the next steps?

Comment: is there a reason why you're downloading it from the github repo? or do you not mind downloading it from anywhere?

Comment: @Ismael its because im going to edit some settings of the extension, then i need to rebuild it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The easiest way will be from the extension directory in your VSCode, you can open that using one of these three ways:
   a. View > Extension
   b. From sidebar, click on extension icon
   c. CTRL + Shift + x

Then search for "gutter preview" with quotations, you'll get one result called Image Preview, that's the extension, just click on install.

2. Another way is visit this url
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kisstkondoros.vscode-gutter-preview.
   Then press on 'Download Extension' on the right hand side, download the file then inside your vscode open the command pallet (CTRL + Shift + p) and type:
   `extensions install from vsix`, click that command, then choose the .VSIX file you just downloaded.
3. And last if you must do it from the github repo, then inside the directory where you ran `npm install` and found the `node_modules` directory, run `npm run webpack-prod` (a command specified in the `package.json` file in the root of the project folder, which describes how to build the app). Then you should find a `.VSIX` file in the `./dist/extension` directory in the project, and you apply step 2 on the generated `.VSIX` file

Answer (score 1):

The process to follow is the same like for any extension development. When you have the code ready to build the extension package follow the [publishing guidelines](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension).

However, instead of really publishing the downloaded extension you would just build the package using:

`vsce package` (see also the Usage section on this page)

If you need to debug the extension code follow the [Your First Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension) page (jumping over the sections that explain how to create the initial extension code). See also the follow up pages like [Extension Anatomy](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/extension-anatomy), which explain more details you might need.